# If $K = I-C$, where $C$ is a square matrix with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then show that $K$ cannot have an eigenvalue $0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods

Given that for $C = (c_{jk})$, $\sum_{k=1}^n |c_{jk}| < 1.$

And given that Gershgorin's theorem says if $\lambda$ is the eigen value of $C$, then for some $1\le j \le n$ $$|c_{jj}-\lambda|\le \sum_{(k\not= j) {k=1}}^n |c_{jk}|.$$

I don't know how to combine all the given information properly to show $K$ has a non-zero eigenvalue. Any help will be greatly appreciated. I've been stuck at this for hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$0$ is an eigenvalue of $K$ if and only if $\lambda = 1$ is an eigenvalue of $C$. We show that this is not possible.

Suppose $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $C$, then:
$|\lambda| = |\lambda - c_{jj} + c_{jj}| \leq |\lambda - c_{jj}| + |c_{jj}| \leq \sum_{k \neq j, k = 1}|c_{jk}| + |c_{jj}| = \sum_{k=1}^{n}|c_{jk}| < 1$.

Comment: Thank you for your help. If possible, can you please also help me how would I need to go about showing that the spectral radius of $C$ is less than one?

Comment: The spectral radius: $\rho(C) = \text{max} \{|\lambda|, \lambda \in \text{Spec}(C) \}$. We have shown in the answer above that $|\lambda| <1$ for all $\lambda \in \text{Spec}(C)$